# How can I add a cover image that sits on top of my bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have three images that are rotating in a full page carousel. I'm trying to add a "cover" image, so to speak, that sits on top of the three rotating. This image will have a cutout that allows you to see the three rotating behind it. I'm just not sure where to place this image in the HTML or what the css would look like.

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</header>

<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 500, //changes the speed
    pause: false
})
</script>

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the cover image should always be displayed above the carousel while the carousel images rotate ?!

Comment: create a fiddle that wil help other to answer you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I understood your question. You could add a div inside the header tag, on top and make it absolute positioned to sit on top. Adjust z-index if needed and don't forget to have header as position: relative.

Comment: So a div in the header, inside the div my img tag with my image. What z-index # do you use to ensure it is always on top of the three rotating?

Comment: Try something like:
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="beOnTop">Your content</div>
.... the rest of the content ....
</header>

On your css file, give this beOnTop div position absolute, width, height, and place it where you want. put a higher z-index then the element that should be in the back. To make sure you can put something like 9999999.